# How to set parentId in Child Entity of one to many mapping using Spring Boot Data JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

**Use Case:** We have one - many bidirectional relationships and we will be receiving requests to update as a parent which contains either child being modified or not.

**Technology stack**

- Spring boot 2.0.2
- Spring data Jpa

***Sample Code:***

**Parent Class Entity:**

```
package com.example.demo.model;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

import org.hibernate.annotations.DynamicInsert;
import org.hibernate.annotations.DynamicUpdate;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@DynamicInsert
@DynamicUpdate
@Entity
public class Parent {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String a;

    private String b;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "parent")
    private Set<Child> childs = new HashSet<>();

    public void addChild(Child child) {
        childs.add(child);
        child.setParent(this);
    }

    public void removeChild(Child child) {
        childs.remove(child);
        child.setParent(null);
    }

    public void setChilds(
            Set<Child> childrens) {
        if (this.childs == null) {
            this.childs = childrens;
        }
        else {
            this.childs.retainAll(childrens);
            this.childs.addAll(childrens);
        }
    }

}
```

**Child Class Entity**

```
package com.example.demo.model;

import java.util.Objects;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.UniqueConstraint;

import org.hibernate.annotations.DynamicInsert;
import org.hibernate.annotations.DynamicUpdate;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@DynamicInsert
@DynamicUpdate
@Entity
@Table(name = "child", uniqueConstraints = {
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "a", "b", "c", "parent_id" }) })
public class Child {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String a;

    private String b;

    private String c;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
    private Parent parent;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) {
            return true;
        }
        if (!(o instanceof Child)) {
            return false;
        }
        Child that = (Child) o;
        return Objects.equals(getA(), that.getA()) && Objects.equals(getB(), that.getB())
                && Objects.equals(getC(), that.getC());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(getA(), getB(), getC());
    }

}
```

**Repository Class:**

```
package com.example.demo.model;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface ParentRepository extends JpaRepository<Parent, Long> {

    @Query("select p from Parent p join fetch p.childs where p.a = ?1")
    Parent findByA(String a);
}
```

**Main-Class with the business case:**

```
package com.example.demo;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.util.Assert;

import com.example.demo.model.Child;
import com.example.demo.model.Parent;
import com.example.demo.model.ParentRepository;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    ParentRepository repository;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        Child c1 = new Child();
        c1.setA("a1");
        c1.setB("b1");
        c1.setC("c1");
        Child c2 = new Child();
        c2.setA("a2");
        c2.setB("b2");
        c2.setC("c2");
        Parent p = new Parent();
        p.addChild(c1);
        p.addChild(c2);
        p.setA("a");

        repository.save(p);

        // This works till now

        // We will get the request for updating parent which might contain removal or addition of the child

        Parent retrievedParent = repository.findByA("a");
        retrievedParent.setB("b");

        Child c4 = new Child();
        c4.setA("a2");
        c4.setB("b2");
        c4.setC("c2");
        Child c3 = new Child();
        c3.setA("a3");
        c3.setB("b3");
        c3.setC("c3");

        //If we know that c1 is removed and c3 is added we can use synchronize methods written in Parent
        //As we don't know which are removed and which are added also as we won't get the id from request passing them 
        // directly to set to let hibernate handle it as equals and Hashcode is already written.

        Set<Child> childrens = new HashSet<>();
        childrens.add(c3);
        childrens.add(c4);
        retrievedParent.setChilds(childrens);

        Parent persistedParent = repository.save(retrievedParent);
        for (Child child : persistedParent.getChilds()) {
            Assert.notNull(child.getParent(), "Parent must not be null");
            //For child 3 it is failing
        }
    }


}
```

With above code, it is unable to set the parent id for child entity 4, if we print SQL logs we can observe that child with id 1 is deleted and child with id 3 is inserted which is expected.

As a workaround I am iterating all child entries and if the parent is not set then setting manually. I don't want this extra update statement.

Other approaches tried, removing all child entries using synchronized removeChild method and then add remaining one by one using synchronized addChild method . This is causing unique constraint failure exception.

**What is required?**
Setting the parent instead of workaround in the insert statement when it is executed.

Comment: When you add a child, you're setting its parent to `this`, which is correct. So you should do the same thing when setting the children. This method could be reduced to `this.childs.clear(); children.forEach(this::addChild);`. I would also fix the English. The plural of child is children. Not childs. Not childrens.

Comment: Do you mean in the setChilds of the parent entity??

Comment: Yes, that's where you're "setting the children".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem comes from this part:

```
Set<Child> childrens = new HashSet<>();
childrens.add(c3);
childrens.add(c4);
retrievedParent.setChilds(childrens);
```

You never need to rewrite a managed collection.

Now, based on your design:

> If we know that c1 is removed and c3 is added we can use synchronize
> methods written in Parent.
>
> As we don't know which are removed and
> which are added also as we won't get the id from request passing them
> directly to set to let hibernate handle it as equals and Hashcode
> is already written.

If the client sends you a collection of entries, you need to [do the matching yourself](https://vladmihalcea.com/merge-entity-collections-jpa-hibernate/), meaning that you need to:

- add new elements
- remove elements that are no longer needed
- update the existing ones